# Python package collections is not installed

Tags: python, collections

I can't install the collections package.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RixjE.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNzF7.png)

i tried to uninstall and reinstall python.

Answer (score 0):

The package you're using isn't maintained and doesn't work with newer versions of python - the github repo for it has some alternatives: https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/issues/435